# Knockout css binding in a foreach

Tags: internet-explorer-8, knockout.js

In a `<ul>` foreach binding, I want knockout to add a dynamic css class to each `<li>`.

The objects I'm binding to look like this:

```
{
    id: 1234,
    class: "foo",
}
```

I want knockout to add the `class` property of each item to the corresponding `<li>`, like so:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: TheList">
    <li data-bind="css: class" />
</ul>
```

So that my [effective] output is like this:

```
<ul>
    <li class="foo" />
    <li class="bar" />
    <li class="etc" />
</ul>
```

I can't figure out the binding syntax. I've tried this,

```
<li data-bind="css: class" />
```

It throws an error:

> Unable to parse bindings. Message: SyntaxError: Syntax error; Bindings value: css: class

I've tried this,

```
<li data-bind="css: $data.class" />
```

It throws an error:

> Unable to parse bindings. Message: SyntaxError: Expected identifier; Bindings value: css: $data.class

I wrapped `class` in quotes to avoid js keyword conflict,

```
<li data-bind="css: 'class'" />
```

This does not throw an error, but it yields unexpected results. I'm 100% positive that "trim" is not one of the `class` property values of any item in the collection:

```
<li class="trim" data-bind="css: 'class'" __ko__1354588574237="ko3">
```

I don't know how or if I can use a computed in this case because AFAIK I can't pass a variable (like`$index` or `$data`) into the computed, therefore the computed can't know which item to return `class` for.

What is the appropriate binding syntax for this scenario, is it possible?

### Solution / Workarounds

This appears to be a `css:` binding issue in IE8 when the property is named 'class'. Here are 3 different workarounds if you run into it:

Change the name of the field to something other than 'class' (if you have control of the source).

Or, you can modify the objects in the list so that the value is accessible from a different name, i.e.,

```
for (var i = 0; i < TheList.length; i++)
{
    TheList[i].safeName = TheList[i]['class'];
}
```

Or,  you can use the `attr:` binding instead of the `css:` binding, which does not appear to suffer from the same issue and can use members called 'class' so long as they are encased in quotes:

```
<li data-bind="attr: { 'class': 'class' } />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should work:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: TheList">
    <li data-bind="css: $data['class'], text: $data['class']" />
</ul>​
```

i think you're running into a keyword issue with `class`.  [working jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dRBbr/).

Comment: Thanks nathan. I think this might be an IE8 problem... I'll have to check my code in another browser. In IE8 (where this needs to work, unfortunately) that jsfiddle is throwing "Expected identifier, string or number". In my proj, the binding to $data['class'] yields that wacky "trim" result (same as when I bind to 'class' in quotes).

Comment: @with, huh, i see that same thing in ie8.  weird.  not to be dismissive, but why not just change the field name?

Comment: Yea it's not a great property name, the data comes from a 3rd party API. I believe you're right that it has something to do with a property named 'class', I think it's a specific issue with the css: binding on IE8. There's a few workarounds if anyone runs into this: you can rename the field (if you have control of the source) you can can duplicate the value into a new field on the object, or you can avoid using the css: binding in favor of an attr: binding to the class element.